# How to work with Django inline forms?

Tags: python, django

I have two models (Receipt and Ingredient) and want to create ingredients when creating receipt.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from .models import Receipt, Ingredient, CookingStep


class ReceiptForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = Receipt
    fields = ('name', 'description', 'hour', 'minute', 'multivarka',)

ReceiptFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Receipt, Ingredient, fields=('name', 'count', 'value'))
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Receipt(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  description = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
  hour = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  minute = models.IntegerField(default=1)
  multivarka = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % (self.name)

class Ingredient(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  count = models.IntegerField(default=0) #200gr, 1kg etc
  value = models.CharField(max_length=255) #gramm, kg etc
  receipts = models.ForeignKey(Receipt)

  def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % (self.name)
```

**views.py**

```
def receipt_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = ReceiptForm(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            created_receipt = formset.save(commit=False)
            new_formset = ReceiptFormSet(request.POST, instance=created_receipt)
            if new_formset.is_valid():
              created_receipt.save()
              new_formset.save()
              return redirect('/receipts')
    else:
        formset = ReceiptForm()
        inline_form = ReceiptFormSet()
    return render(request, 'admin_site/receipt_edit.html', {'formset': formset})
```

**receipt_edit.html**

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>New receipt</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ formset.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Now only form for creating receipt is displayed. I want to have two forms on edit page: firstly form for receipt and then form for creating ingredient for this receipt (on one page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, use some consistent names for your variables. Your `ReceiptForm` instance is a form, not a formset, so call it `form`. Let's call your `ReceiptFormSet` instance `formset` everywhere.

Next, you need to include your form and formset in the template context when you call `render`.

```
def receipt_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ReceiptForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            created_receipt = form.save(commit=False)
            formset = ReceiptFormSet(request.POST, instance=created_receipt)
            if formset.is_valid():
              created_receipt.save()
              formset.save()
              return redirect('/receipts')
    else:
        form = ReceiptForm()
        formset = ReceiptFormSet(instance=Receipt())

    return render(request, 'admin_site/receipt_edit.html', {'form': form, 'formset': formset})
```

Finally, you need to include your form and formset in the template.

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    {{ formset }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```